# как в методе отображать ИЗМЕНЕННЫЙ параметр

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

как в методе myItem (show.myItem) отображать ИЗМЕНЕННЫЙ параметр this.item , если этот параметр меняется внутри класса

[gist](https://gist.github.com/dalmariko/8943a2e16de75c3193498ba89ab99df6)

```js
class Click{
   constructor(item){
       this.item=item;
       this.init;
   }

   get init(){
       this.addItem;
       this.addinTime;
   }

   get addinTime(){
       setTimeout(()=>{
           this.addItem;
       },5000)
   }
  get addItem(){
         this.item+=10;
      //console.log(this.item);
   }
   get myItem(){
       return this.item;
   }


}

let show= new Click(20);
console.log(show.myItem);
```

Comment: Подождать пять секунд, а потом вызвать `myItem`.

Comment: @Igor  а ещё варианты? Если нужно этот параметр передать после изменения в другой класс?

Comment: Подождите. Вы сами написали код, который вызывает метод, прибавляющий к свойству `10`, так, чтобы это происходило асинхронно через несколько секунд. А теперь говорите: "А результат того, что произойдет через пять секунд, я хочу сейчас." Ничего не смущает?

Comment: Сделайте в Вашем классе событие, которое вызывается из `addItem`, и получайте значение в этом событии.

Comment: @Igor Может я неправильно задал вопрос, в общем в нутри класса происходят изменения. И мне нужно что бы эти изменения были доступны.

Comment: @dpi, эти изменения и доступны: свойство `myItem` при каждом обращении будет возвращать актуальное значение `item`

Comment: @Grundy а как сделать что бы myItem вызывался когда изменилось значение item?

Comment: @dpi, что ты имеешь ввиду под _myItem вызывался_? Вызывался где? Вызывался кем? Вызывался в какой момент времени? Для чего?

Comment: Если тебе нужно знать об изменениях чего-то, можешь сделать событие на которое можно подписаться, как это было указано выше в комментариях, и вызывать обработчик в момент смены значения. На данный момент вопрос слишком абстрактный, поэтому и ответ на него тоже будет довольно общим

Answer (score -1):

```
class Click{
   constructor(item){
       this.item=item;
       this.init;
       this.myItemPromise;
   }

   get init(){
       this.addItem;
       this.addinTime;
   }

   get addinTime(){
      this.myItemPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
              this.addItem;
              resolve();
          },5000)
      }).then(()=>delete this.myItemPromise)
   }
  get addItem(){
         this.item+=10;
      //console.log(this.item);
   }
   async get myItem(){
       if (this.myItemPromise) await this.myItemPromise;
       return this.item;
   }

}

let show= new Click(20);
show.myItem.then(console.log)
```